# DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Ajax error. Using laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Im trying to show data from mongodb database and its show like this
DataTables warning: table id=tblConsent - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
idont know why please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WXF7.png)

This is the view.blade.php and the sript

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var Modal = null;
    
        $('.btnSearch').click(function () {
            reloadTable();
        });
    
        function reloadTable() {
            ConsentTable.draw();
        }
    
        var ConsentTable = $('#tblConsent').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            iDisplayLength: 25,
            "searching": false,
            ajax: {
                url: '{!! route('consent.setting.consent.consent_datatables') !!}',
                data: function (data) {
                    data.title_th_search = $('#title_th_search').val();
                    data.status_search = $('#status_search').val();
                    data.type_search = $('#type_search').val();
                    data.start_date_search = $('#start_date_search').val();
                    data.end_date_search = $('#end_date_search').val();
                }
            },
            pagerSettings: {
                searchOnEnter: true,
                firstIcon: "icon-double-angle-left fa-2x",
                previousIcon: "icon-angle-left fa-2x",
                nextIcon: "icon-angle-right fa-2x",
                lastIcon: "icon-double-angle-right fa-2x"
            },
            aaSorting: [[0, 'asc']],
            oLanguage: {
                sProcessing: "<div style=\"text-align:center;position: absolute; right: 50%;\"><img src=\"../template/admin/img/loading-6.gif\" /></div>",
                sInfoFiltered: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'consent_id', name: 'consent_id'},
                {data: 'consent_title_th', name: 'consent_title_th'},
                {data: 'start_date', name: 'start_date'},
                {data: 'end_date', name: 'end_date'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ],
            fnDrawCallback: function () {
                var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.switchery');
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    var switchery = new Switchery(elems[i]);
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is my controller

```
 public function getDataTableConsent(Request $request)
    {
        $getConsentDatatable = Consent::select(
            'consents._id as consent_id',
            'consents.title_th as consent_title_th',
            'consents.start_date',
            'consents.end_date',
            'consents.version',
            'consents.created_at',
            'consents.updated_at',
            'consents.status',
        )
            ->where(function ($group) use ($request) {
                if ($request->get('title_th_search')) {
                    $group->where('consents.title_th', 'LIKE', "%$request->title_th_search%");
                }
            })
            ->where(function ($group) use ($request) {
                if ($request->get('status_search')) {
                    $group->where('consents.status', 'LIKE', "%$request->status_search%");
                }
            })
            ->where(function ($group) use ($request) {
                if ($request->get('type_search')) {
                    $group->where('consents.type', 'LIKE', "%$request->type_search%");
                }
            })
            ->where(function ($group) use ($request) {
                if ($request->get('status_search') == '-') {
                } else {
                    $group->where('consents.status', '=', $request->get('status_search'));
                }
            })
            ->where(function ($group) use ($request) {
                if ($request->get('start_date_search') == '-') {
                } else {
                    $group->where('consents.start_date', '=', $request->get('start_date_search'));
                }
            })
            ->where(function ($group) use ($request) {
                if ($request->get('end_date_search') == '-') {
                } else {
                    $group->where('consents.end_date', '=', $request->get('end_date_search'));
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('consents._id', 'asc')
            ->get();
        return Datatables::of($getConsentDatatable)
            ->editColumn('status', function ($value) {
                $html = '';
                if ($value->status == 1) {
                    $html .= '<span style="font-size: 13px;" class="label label-flat border-success text-success-300">Active</span>';
                } else {
                    $html .= '<span style="font-size: 13px;" class="label label-flat border-danger text-danger-300">Inactive</span>';
                }
                return $html;
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($value) {
                return '
            <ul class="icons-list">
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-menu9"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li> <a title="แก้ไข" onclick="javascript:editAdmin(' . $value->admin_id . ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit </a> </li>
            <li> <a title="ลบ" onclick="javascript:deleteAdmin(' . $value->admin_id . ',\' ' . $value->email . ' \')"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete </a> </li> 
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['status','action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Comment: You get this error on **Network** > **Response** [See this image](https://datatables.net/media/images/tn/1/chrome-4.png)

Comment: the error with ajax response one more thing your query of $getConsentDatatable, the way of selecting data from Eloquent is wrong you should use like this 

User::select(['id','name as fullname'])